# Twilio is faililing to send message after I return the twiml message for windows

Tags: node.js, twilio-twiml

But it's working for fedora. How can I fix this?

```js
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message(showDefaultMessage(userName));
  return res.status(200).send(twiml.toString());
}
```

I was trying to send message from node server on node version 18 to client but this only works in fedora not windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this issue is aparently Windows-specific but I can see you're missing to set the content type which would explain why the express server returns an invalid response.

Try this:

```js
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message(showDefaultMessage(userName));
  res.type("text/xml");
  res.send(twiml.toString());
}
```

> FYI: `res.status(200)` and `return` are actually not needed here but don't do harm either.